# Erlang port driver communicating with C program

Tags: erlang, system, driver, distributed, port

If I want my Erlang process connect with a C shared lib I use Erlang linked in port driver.

As I want my C program stores some data structures to respond to erlang calls, I must use global variables.

Is there any problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are running a c-programme in its own process and talking to it over a pipe - Erlang can't see the memory space of your C programme and doesn't care how you write it. You Erlang VM is not dependant on your port driver - that's what the architecture is for.